# Android as BLE peripheral does not show the CCCD descriptor when central discovers services, characteristic and descriptors being advertised

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, descriptor, ads, bluetooth-peripheral

When my central device tries to discover the services, characteristics and its descriptor everything is discovered fine but when the central device tries to search for the Client Configuration Characteristic Descriptor for a characteristic which has notify property it does not find it.

This is how I described my characteristic :

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic responseCharacteristic = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(Constants.rUuid,
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY,
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ);
```

My descriptor :

```
BluetoothGattDescriptor notifyDescriptor = new BluetoothGattDescriptor(Constants.nUuid, 
  BluetoothGattDescriptor.PERMISSION_READ );
```

Adding the descriptor to the Characteristic

```
responseCharacteristic.addDescriptor(notifyDescriptor);
```

Please see this image from the sniffer which shows that the central device tries to look for the descriptor of type "0x2902" by there is no reply after that

[image: sniffer screenshot]

Whereas other characteristics and services are discovered fine

[image: Service and characteristics sniffer screenshot]

Can anyone please let me know why is this happening ? Did anyone see any such issues while working with Nexus5X as your BLE peripheral?

Comment: I guess your descriptor should be writable.

Comment: Yeah I already tried that. But that didn't fix the issue.
The problem was that I wasn't responding to the Descriptor read request. So during the discovery of the descriptor there was a callback to the onDescriptorReadRequest in which we have to send a response back to the central device. Once I added that the descriptor got discovered and everything worked fine!